# Generic Type Gson deserializer

Tags: android, json, gson

I have an Api which the api looks like this:
If the response is ok the structure will begin with `data` keyword for example:

```
{
"data": {
"name": "Rogelio Volkman",
"address": "27299 Will Bridge Suite 058\nWest Reubenhaven, MI 00736",
"lat": 54.65,
"lng": 111.75,
"phone": "+26(4)5015498663"
  }
}
```

And if response is not Ok(status is not 200) response will not container `data` keyword so response will look like:

```
{
"message": "404 Not Found",
"status_code": 404
}
```

Since this structure is a common structure for all models I intended to create a Generic Deserializer for all models.
This looked like:

```
public class DataObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

@Override
public Objectdeserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException {
    // Get the "data" element from the parsed JSON
    JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");

    // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
    // to this deserializer
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, Object.class);
  }
}
```

then registered it as typeAdapter `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Object.class, new DataObjectDeserializer()).create();`
Since every object is an instance of Object I supposed this would work (deserialize my `Museum` model) but it didn't.
In my second attempt I created an abstract class called `DataObjectModel` and class `Museum` extended `DataObjectModel`. then created anoteher deserailizer like:
    public class DataObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {

```
@Override
public DataObjectModel deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException {
    // Get the "data" element from the parsed JSON
    JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");

    // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
    // to this deserializer
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, DataObjectModel.class);
 }
}
```

And registered it with Gson like `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(DataObjectModel.class, new DataObjectDeserializer()).create();`. But this didn't deserialize `Museum` model either.

The question is: how can I create a deserializer for parent class which would deserialize child class as well (as my second approach)  Or How can I create a generic class with Gson so that every tyoe that is wrapped aroung `data` can be used with it like:
    public class DataObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {

```
@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException {
    // Get the "data" element from the parsed JSON
    JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");

    // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
    // to this deserializer
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, /* This part not working due to type erasing in java*/ T.calss);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create your response and data structure like this

```
private class Data {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("address")
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;
    @SerializedName("lng")
    private String lng;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    private String phone;

}

private class Response {

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    private int statusCode;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private Data data;

}
```

you can then do

```
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);

if(response.statusCode == 0) {
    //everything ok, do something with response.data
} else {
    //display response.message, data will be null 
}
```

Comment: @EIDuderino yeah, offcourse that would work but that requires I create 2 models for each gson deserialization, which that's not so optimized soloution